# Revert all changes in one particular revision using java library

Tags: java, svn

I have to write a java code which will to revert all changes from one revision and then commit it. It will be equivalent of these commands:

```
svn merge -r 50:49 A/trunk/

svn commit -m "reverting to rev49"
```

Do you know any library which could help me to do it?
(Sorry, for my english it is not my native language)

Comment: Why do you want to do it in java? You already wrote some nice shell code which can be aggregated into the script.

Comment: jenkins / hudson job? ant script?  batch file?

Comment: yes, it will be jenkins plugin. Near each item of revisions list used with new build will be placed "revert" button. It's why i need it in java

Answer (score 1):

try looking at svnkit.  It has a nice working copy api.